# Exposed filter cleaner URL

Tags: views, 8

I have created a custom content type called building which I have added a entity reference field called category which is the vocabulary and added building type terms. I created a view called buildings and added an exposed filter that is listing the building types. I get the listing of the categories by exposing the filter Has Taxonomy Term and then using BEF to list the categories as links rather than a dropdown or autocomplete. Whenever I click each category link for the exposed filter I get the url www.example.com/building?category=1 is there a way to make it use the term name rather than the term id. Also further, is there a way to have it make the url a little cleaner like www.example.com/building/category/buldingtype

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your Exposed filter `Selection type` settings to **Autocomplete** instead of "Dropdown" you will get term names instead of TIDs.

Read more in part of this answer: [How to use URL query parameter on a View Exposed Filter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260987/how-to-use-url-query-parameter-on-a-view-exposed-filter/261000#261000)

There is another way to do it: introduce the term information into the view through a Relationship so you can use the term Name. Read the steps in this answer: [Get taxonomy name instead of id](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271559/get-taxonomy-name-instead-of-id/271602#271602)

That answer also mentions how you can "prettify" the URL: use the [Query Parameters To URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_parameters_to_url) module, [it's being ported to D8](https://www.drupal.org/project/contrib_tracker/issues/2835060).